# What is a turtle mode?

Tags: betaflight, multirotor, turtle-mode

Could you explain what is a turtle mode?

I'm wondering what the use of it is? Does it work on all quadcopters?

Comment: These are good questions but they are a bit too broad. Try to make your question more specific.

Comment: I removed some of the questions to narrow the scope down.

Answer (score 5):

Turtle Mode, Flip Over After Crash in Betaflight, is a mode that allows your drone to flip over if it is upside down by reversing the prop direction and spinning up very rapidly in order to lift a side of the drone so it flips to the upright position.

This is a manual process - the drone doesn't do this automatically when it flips over (you need to enable turtle mode after the crash, manipulate the sticks to flip the drone over, and disable turtle mode in order to resume flight).  It's beneficial because if your drone goes down 100' away, for example, you can put your drone in turtle mode and flip it back to the normal position, and resume flying.

There are some cases where turtle mode won't work, like when you land upside down in tall grass, the grass could bind the motors/props, preventing turtle mode from working effectively.

Answer (score 3):

Betaflight reverses the direction of two of your motors so you can flip over in a crash.

You can enable it as ‘flip over after crash’ in the Betaflight configurator.

And it will only work on drones where the firmware supports it or allows you to configure it.